# How to redirect index page to tab area of about us page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect

In my home slider there is a read more link in each slide. When I click on read more link it redirected to "`industriessolutions_trial.php`" page, there is 4 category in that page. When click on the category the details of that category will show up and there is four tabs as same as previous category(I have used Organic Tabs Plugin) . My question is how can I redirect from home page directly tab area of "`industriessolutions_trial.php`" page??? When click on banner read more link it have to redirect to the respective tabs.

this is my js code of `industriessolutions_trial.php`

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#oil_area").click(function(e){


             $(".offerings_content").hide();
              $("#example-two").show();
               $("#tabOil").trigger("click");
               return false;

        });

        $("#utility_area").click(function(e){


             $(".offerings_content").hide();
              $("#example-two").show();
               $("#tabUtl").trigger("click");
               return false;

        });
        $("#smartbldng_area").click(function(e){
            $(".offerings_content").hide();
              $("#example-two").show();
               $("#tabSmt").trigger("click");
               return false;

        });
        $("#heavy_area").click(function(e){
            $(".offerings_content").hide();
              $("#example-two").show();
               $("#tabHvy").trigger("click");
               return false;

        });
    });
```

this is my tab plugin code

```
$(function() {

            $("#example-two").organicTabs({
                "speed": 200
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as below

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
  url_params = window.location.hash;  
  tabParams = $('a[href="' + url_params + '"]');
  if (tabParams.length === 0) {
        //Activate first tab
        //Show first tab content
  } else {
      tabParams.click();
  }    
});
```

Example url :

http://flutura.com/industriessolutions_trial.php#heavy

when i execute ( window.location.hash) in firebug console.. 
i get tab id as result - #heavy .

So u got tab id now, just show tab contents using above code.In your case, you are showing tab content by clicking anchor link on tab name.So i generated anchor link with jquery and made it click if hash is present in url.

**UPDATE:**

IN read more link,, the href is http://flutura.com/industriessolutions_trial.php#heavy_area .. This will open up heavy area TAB.. I tested

javascript code in industriessolutions_trial page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
  url_params = window.location.hash;   
  if (url_params.length === 0) {
        //Activate first tab
        //Show first tab content
  } else {
      $(url_params).click();
  }     
});
```

Comment: This is your read more url with tab id .. http://flutura.com/industriessolutions_trial.php#heavy

Comment: By the way you are not using tab in that industrial_trial page .. i cant see the code u are using to execute it.. update code in question

Comment: I have updated, In my industriessolutions_trial.php page there is $ categories (Oil N Gas, Utilities, Smart Buildings, Heavy Industries). When click on each category the respective tab are opening i need same   effect when I click read more from index page , I mean the respective tabs should open while clicking read more.

Comment: check my UPDATE in answer.. it will successfully open up heavy industries tab...repeat same process to open tab when it reaches other page.. let me know.